# Unable to pass value to view upon successful redirect

Tags: laravel-5

Hello i am simply trying to pass a value to another page in my code.  basically when the form has finished processsing it should redirect to the next page with a certain value but i keep getting undefined $reference (which is the name of my variable on that page):

```
@section('content')

    <h3>Transaction Complete</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
        <h3 style="margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important;">
            <small>Your Reference Code: </small>
        </h3>
        <div class="col-md-12 ticket-code">
            <h3>
                " {{ $reference }} "
            </h3>

        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

this is the redirect code:

```
$reference = 'REF7625269';
return \Redirect::to('tickets/payment/complete')->with('reference', $reference);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it into an array:

```
return \Redirect::to('tickets/payment/complete')->with(['reference', $reference]);
```

Also, I personally like the redirect helper:

```
return redirect()
       ->to('tickets/payment/complete')
       ->with(['reference', $reference]);
```

or named URLs:

```
return redirect()->route('home.route.name');
```